# Add a webform in a view row

Tags: views, webforms

I have a table View. I want to add a button to each row that is a webform with hidden fields containing data from the row. Clicking on the button executes the webform and returns the user to the row.

e.g. Let's say the rows a types of fruit. I want a button on each row which is "I want this" - clicking on the button will be like submitting a webform, so I can use the webform functionality such as generating emails and having a chronological list of submissions.

If this is not possible with webforms, is there another way to do it?

Comment: did you try webform conditionals

Comment: Webform conditionals doesn't do what I require.

Comment: try this with VBO module